# How to add static .js files to Meteor project?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Sorry for my english. I have a functions.js file, where I put all my js code. The functions.js doesn't refer to Meteor. Where do I place the functions.js file so that it is attached to the template?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you installed meteor and created a meteor project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may place any clients.js file somewhere into your ./client directory. This will be packed and loaded automatically by your app.

If you also need this functions on server, place ist into ./lib directory.

Checkout the meteor guide about application structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to attach functions to a blaze template you can use helpers, events, oncreated ondestroyed onrendered etc. This is done in the client folder or imports for the client side.

In a file that is run on the client create a helper like the example below:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
foo() {
return Session.get("foo");
}
});
```

In the example the helper can be invoked with {{foo}} in the template defined with

```
<template name="myTemplate">
```

Taken from the docs: http://docs.meteor.com/api/templates.html#Template-helpers